# centering and spacing images in an unknown size parent container

Tags: css, width, centering, css-tables

What I am trying to do is centre the img elements both vertically and horizontally inside the img-container. The img-container needs to be a % of the parent element not a fixed width. (ie the outer-container may not always be 1000px)

Although the code below centres the image fine withing the img-container, the width of the img-continer seems to ignore the CSS width 20%. Ie I cannnot get the img-container to get the correct (in this case 200px) width.

Any suggestions?
-Matt.

Here is my CSS

```
#outer-container{
  width:1000px;
}
.img-container {
  height:20vh;
  width:20%;
  vertical-align:middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
.centred-img {
  display:block;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  max-height:100%;
  max-width:100%;
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="outer-container">
  <div class="img-container">
    <img class="centred-img" src="1.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="img-container">
    <img class="centred-img" src="2.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="img-container">
    <img class="centred-img" src="3.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="img-container">
    <img class="centred-img" src="4.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle or jsbin of it

Comment: this shows the issues I am having with different sized images. http://jsfiddle.net/banditturnbull/7LVSd/1/

Answer (score 1):

Use `display:inline-block` on the child elements and use `text-align:center` on the parent.
That should do the trick for horizontal centring. To make it centre vertically, you need to
add `line-height` to your images parent and `vertical-align:middle` to image itself.

Try using this CSS`.`

```
#outer-container{
  width:500px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
.img-container {
  height:20vh;
  width:20%;
  display: inline-block;
  border:1px solid black;
  line-height:20vh;
  text-align: center;
}
.centred-img {
  vertical-align:middle;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  max-height:100%;
  max-width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that centres the width nicely, but it doesnt vertically centre the images. Im using table cell and vertical-align middle to centre the images.  see http://jsfiddle.net/banditturnbull/7LVSd/1/

Comment: Sorry, still same problem - changing away from table-cell looses the vertical centering.

Comment: @user3237002 it works for me in your fiddle, did you replace your css with mine?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my fiddle just using css tables. Is this what you're looking for? The height and width are both dynamic.

http://jsfiddle.net/sinnix/dpppzuds/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50">
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50">
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50">
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.container {
    display: table;
    width: 90%; /* adjust as desired */
    height: 100px;
}

.row {
    display: table-row;
}

.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 25%;
    background: magenta;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

.cell:nth-child(even){
    background: yellow;
}
```